# remote sending post in cURL PHP

Tags: php, post, curl

im trying to send sms remotly on address "smssheep.com" and i set all POST FIELDS and all and post but it wont work...

CODE:

```
$settings=array();
$settings["name"]="form1"; //name of form
$settings["no"]="0038268000000"; //mobile number
$settings["msg"]="TEST TEST MESAGE"; //message to send
$settings["submit"]="saveForm";
$settings["x_form_secret"]="**********";
$settings["idstamp"]="***************";

$url="http://smssheep.com/sendsms.php";

$ch=curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $settings);
curl_exec($ch);
```

Comment: Does PHP output any error? have you checked what error does cURL returns with curl_error() ?

Comment: there is no PHP errors, its in cURL, but cant find out what is problem... always get message "Your Message has already been processed!" ... and i submit all hidden fields

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try this (I have stared some of your information in some of `$settings` indexes):**

```
<?php

$settings = array();
$settings["name"] = "form1";
$settings["no"] = "*********";
$settings["msg"] = "TEST TEST MESAGE";
$settings["submit"] = "saveForm";
$settings["x_form_secret"] = "*********";
$settings["idstamp"] = "*********";

$settings = http_build_query($settings);

$url = "http://smssheep.com/sendsms.php";

$ch = curl_init($url);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $settings);

curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

?>
```

And please do not post your secret information in public!

Comment: Thanks for fast answer, i try this but don't work... i always get output message "Your Message has already been processed!"..
Security number always change so i manage to get it with curl...

Comment: Maybe because you have already sent a Text to that number with same text? Could you try another text? To make sure that your POST request is working, make a php page and direct your request to it and in that page just put the POST content in a file via `print_r($_POST, true)` and `file_put_contents`, if your POST request is working then you may need to contact the support of your service provider.

Comment: i just check, $_POST working...
also i change message, number, and dont work again...

Comment: So your code is correct, you need to contact your service provider to get technical support about this, tell them you are sending a post request with those parameters and it's not working, if you are trying to simulate a form without permission, then may be blocking this by checking IP or HTTP referer ...